# how to display information in jsp page from controller Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I need display data in jsp with controller, i have `List` with information for print in jsp.

When run this code i get error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [entities.Pupil]: No default constructor found; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: entities.Pupil.()

**Controller**

```
 @Controller
   public class PupilController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List add(@ModelAttribute Pupil pupil){
        System.out.println(pupil.toString());
        List<Pupil> pupilList = new ArrayList<Pupil>();
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(1, "Name", "Last", 13));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(2, "Name", "Last", 55));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(3, "Name", "Last", 41));
        return pupilList;
    }
   }
```

**index.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <a href="hello">click</a>
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <p>1:</p><input type="text" name="one">
        <p>2:</p><input type="text" name="two">
        <p>3:</p><input type="text" name="three">
        <p>4:</p><input type="text" name="four">
        <input type="submit" value="button">
    </form>
</body>
```

**add.jsp**

```
<body>
  <h3>This is add.jsp</h3>
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>NAME</td>
            <td>LAST</td>
            <td>YEAR</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <c:forEach  items="${pupilList}" var="tester">
            <tr>
                <td>${tester.id}</td>
                <td>${tester.name}</td>
                <td>${tester.last}</td>
                <td>${tester.year}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Make a default constructor in your `Pupil` class.

Comment: Oh, i create default constructor in `Pupil` class, but in jsp page don't show data from `pupilList` only `thead` block

Comment: Change return type of controller method from `List` to `List<Pupil>`

Comment: changed but it did not help

Comment: Did you include the tag lib for `<c:forEach>` in your jsp? Tag lib `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Comment: No, i did not add it, but when add i get error:
`HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`

Comment: Include [jstl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl/1.2) in your pom

Comment: I add dependency jstl and this code work, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have converted above comments into an answer.

Comment: okey, I mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make below changes in your code.

1. Add `default constructor` in your Pupil class.
2. Add tag lib in your jsp file. `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`
3. Include pom entry for [JSTL](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl/1.2).

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute Pupil pupil){
        System.out.println(pupil.toString());
        List<Pupil> pupilList = new ArrayList<Pupil>();
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(1, "Name", "Last", 13));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(2, "Name", "Last", 55));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(3, "Name", "Last", 41));
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.addObject(pupilList);
        return view;
    }
```

Or

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@ModelAttribute Pupil pupil, ModelMap model){
        System.out.println(pupil.toString());
        List<Pupil> pupilList = new ArrayList<Pupil>();
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(1, "Name", "Last", 13));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(2, "Name", "Last", 55));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(3, "Name", "Last", 41));
        model.put("pupilList", pupilList);
        return "page-name";
    }
```

Comment: how get information on jsp? if use this solution in jsp need use `getAttribute`?

Comment: @BohdanOlehovich, these both approach are same as yours. The only difference is that in case of your approach you can only use `add.jsp` where as in these approaches you can specify different jsp name.

Comment: No you don't need to use `getAttribute` http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam